# Labeling in MIPS with branches statements

Tags: assembly, mips

Does a label still execute if it is not specifically called?

Assuming I have

```
beq $t0, $t1, LABEL1
LABEL1: add $t0,$t2,$t1
beq $t0, $t3, LABEL2
LABEL2: add $t0, $t3, $t4
```

When I run this, will LABEL2 happen even if $t0 and $t3 are not equal?

Comment: The statement at LABEL1 and also at LABEL2 will execute regardless. Both conditional branches are essentially nops since if either branch succeeds it branches to the following instruction and if it fails it falls through to the following instruction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I run this, [will] `LABEL2` happen even if `$t0` and `$t3` are not equal?

Yes.
Although a label doesn't really execute: a label is just a name that you've given to a specific location in your program, which helps you refer to that location in a simple manner. It's the *instructions* that are executed.

Comment: I see.  Thank you for the clarification.  As a follow up, what would be a way of skipping that instruction if I didn't want it to execute?  Is a jump the way to go?

Comment: Yes, a jump past the code you don't want to execute is the normal way to do it (i.e. replace the `beq` with a `bne` to somewhere else). Some processor architectures (e.g. ARM) also have conditional execution where you can specify for each instruction under which condition it should execute.